# Can someone explain this weird behaviour (nodejs + mongoose)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to access a specific object inside an array in my MongoDB using an id sent from the client, but somehow it returns **undefined** even though the element with that id exists.

The code:

```
router.put('/odgovor/:slug', async(req, res, next)=>{   
    const date = new Date();
    const month = new Array();
    month[0] = 'Januar';
    month[1] = 'Februar';
    month[2] = 'Mart';
    month[3] = 'April';
    month[4] = 'Maj';
    month[5] = 'Jun';
    month[6] = 'Jul';
    month[7] = 'Avgust';
    month[8] = 'Septembar';
    month[9] = 'Oktobar';
    month[10] = 'Novembar';
    month[11] = 'Decembar';
    await Post.findOne({slug: req.params.slug}, async(err, post)=>{
        if(err) return next();
        if(!post) return next();

        console.log(post.comments[req.body.commentId]);
        console.log(req.body.commentId);
        console.log(post.comments[12]);

        /*const reply = {
            id: post.comments[req.body.commentId].replies.length,
            date: `${date.getDate()} ${month[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()} ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`,
            user: req.body.user,
            username: req.body.username,
            comment: req.body.comment
        }
        post.comments[req.body.commentId].replies.push(reply);
        try{
            post = await post.save();
            res.redirect(`/poezija/${req.params.slug}`);
        }catch(e){
            res.render('errors/500', {token: res.locals.token});
        }*/
    });
});
```

The console:

```
undefined
12
{
  id: 12,
  date: '9 Decembar 2020 20:48',
  user: 'name',
  username: 'tests',
  comment: 'tests',
  replies: []
}
```

What's even more strange, the req.body.commentId is 12 and if I do:

```
console.log(post.comments[req.body.commentId]);
```

it returns undefined, but if I do:

```
console.log(post.comments[12]);
```

it returns the actual object.

Can someone explain, please?

Comment: Don't pass an `async function` as a callback. Especially if you're not even using `await`!

Comment: Does `req.body.commentId` have a space or any other invisible characters in it? Try printing `req.body.commentId.length`

Comment: What is `typeof req.body.commentId`?

Comment: @Bergi I'm actually using it, I just excluded it as I didn't want that part of the code to be processed. Apologies, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: @RepFabrika Even then, don't pass a callback to mongoose methods at all. Just `await` the promise for the post that `findOne` returns, and put your code in the line after it.

Comment: Oh my dumbass... It was indeed a string. Thank you @VLAZ and Bergi !

Comment: Object keys are strings anyway, `obj[12]` and `obj["12"]` are the same thing. The problem is whether you're not actually trying to do `obj["12 "]` or similar

Comment: @VLAZ Right, switching from java made forget that JS is weakly typed... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback returns a mongoose Document object as a second argument. Calling the `toObject` method on the result will convert it to a javascript object and it might fix the issue.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-toObject).

Comment: I already found the solution, but that is useful to know. Cheers!